# How to merge two arrays at run time

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, typescript

I am getting below like values at runtime. Below is for only example. I will have same array structure at runtime. I want to merge them.

```js
let finalSearchResult =[];
data [{"a":1000,"a":1000001,"a":10000002,"D":5000000}]
data [{"P":1000,"Q":1000001,"R":10000002,"S":5000000}]
finalSearchResult.concat(finalSearchResult,data);
```

but its not working. When I am printing finalSearchResult its coming as null.

Comment: What is the desired output?

Answer (score 1):

The `concat()` method is used to merge two or more arrays. This method does not change the existing arrays, but instead returns a new array.
please refer to:
[Array.prototype.concat documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Therefore:

```
finalSearchResult = finalSearchResult.concat(data);
```

Will be the correct way to concat the arrays.

Comment: no. Its giving me an empty array while printing in console,